# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application calls Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In the same solution, I have an MVC 4 Web Application project ("the site") and an MVC 4 Web API project ("the service").

In future, I may want to deploy the service on separate server from the site.

Therefore, I would like the site's model class to call the into the service's web methods.

Is this possible ?  How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, why don't you just create the site's model as a separate project in your solution.  Your site would reference it.  The model would make calls to your web API over HttpWebRequest or something similar.

Comment: Why does the site model need to be a separate project ?  I'm ok with using HttpWebRequest from within my site's model class, but how to construct the url to my service api ?  UrlHelper.GenerateUrl() assumes in-scope MVC app ..

Comment: No reason why you'd *have to* create your model in a separate project, but I generally do for testability reasons.  I create an interface, implement the interface, etc. for mocking purposes.
I think you should just create the base URL as a property on your model class.  Then you can have the site set it (perhaps you store it as an application setting in web.config) when it calls the model. You can change the web.config setting when you move the service.